# Sharepoint page loads very slow couple of hours in the moring, typically 9-10 AM

Tags: sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a site in SharePoint farm which has 4 front-end web servers. Every morning all sites in that farm loads very slow, sometimes up to 50 seconds. This happens typically between 9-10 AM. The traffic is routed via a load balancer.

I tried to setup a site outside of SP without authentication, and that site is not having the  same problem, so traffic and server load is not an issue.

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be morning peak.

There may be many reasons of it. I think of these:

1. database. your SQL can be under pressure. Enable developer dashboard in ondemand mode and check the execution times of SharePoint SQL commands.
2. AD. When using NTLM authentication each request to SP is validated. The validation involves communication within SP web server and AD controler.
3. Check jobs and especially Search crawling configuration. Search index updating is very resource consuming and even if you have dedicated search server crawling changed items can utilize your servers and database very much.